# Linq return first date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the query:

```
var q = db.tblArcadeGamePlays
    .Where(c => c.GameID == GameID && c.ReferalID != 0 && c.ReferalID != null)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.ReferalID })
    .Select(g => new { Plays = g.Count(), URL = g.Key.ReferalID })
    ;
```

`tblArcadeGamePlays` also has a field `Date`, in the group I'd like to return the earliest observed date that group contains.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
.Select(g => new {
       Plays = g.Count(), URL = g.Key.ReferalID,
       MinDate = g.Min(x => x.Date
});
```

you *might* also find the LINQ syntax easier to read/maintain here, but... the extension syntax will work too. But as LINQ:

```
var q = from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays
        where c.GameID == GameID && c.ReferalID != 0 && c.ReferalID != null
        group c by c.ReferalID into g
        select new {
            Plays = g.Count(), URL = g.Key.ReferalID, MinDate = g.Min(x=>x.Date)
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work

```
var firstIndex = q.Min(c => c.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = db.tblArcadeGamePlays     .Where(c => c.GameID == GameID && c.ReferalID != 0 && c.ReferalID != null)     .GroupBy(r => new { r.ReferalID })     .Select(g => new { Plays = g.Count(), URL = g.Key.ReferalID , Date = g.Min(cc=>cc.DateField) })     ;
```

Replace DateField with your actual property